# Is it safe to pull a docker pre-image from Dockerhub in production?

Tags: azure, docker, security, containers

I am new to using Docker and I am about to deploy a dockerized model. The pre-image that I pull for the container is from a remote repository (actually, https://mcr.microsoft.com/), using the "latest" tag.

But I noticed, when the container restarts it fails, every now and then, to pull the image correctly, and the container becomes unhealthy and requires manual fixing.

Does this instability mean that I should prefer some local repositories where I clone these "official images" to them?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: My day job exclusively uses a mirror due to the Docker Hub rate limiting, and it can be a good practice to insulate yourself from external services.  But that's more of a system-administration question than a programming question, and it wouldn't answer why sometimes your application fails.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze for your reply. But what if, for instance, the external host suddenly stop providing the pre-image. In fact, I checked the logs, and the reason for failure was that pulling from the external repo was not successful. Anyways, I was interested in knowing whether it is big NO to use pre-images in this way in production - and apparently it is a normal practice?

Comment: YES @Avocado Its about an images that you can use it safely for ex: if you are using a popular webserver or certain programming language in docker it will be better to go with official image(ex:dockerhub.com) because there is a guarantee that it does not contain a malicious code.